# I need help finding the roots of a characteristic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I am trying to find the roots of characteristic polynomials.

This can be difficult to do by hand, especially when I have a characteristic polynomial of the 3rd or 4th degree.

I always try to factorise the polynomial, but it doesn't always work.

I start by guessing simple roots like 1,2,-1,-2...

I want help in finding the roots in a shorter period of time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have the rational root  test.

If you have a polynomial of this type:

${\displaystyle a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{0}=0}$
with integer coefficients ${\displaystyle a_{i}\in \mathbb {Z} }$.

The test tells you that each rational solution $x = \frac{p}{q}$, written in lowest terms so that p and q are relatively prime, satisfies:

p is an integer factor of the constant term $a_0$, and
q is an integer factor of the leading coefficient $a_n$.

All the rational (racionals and integers) roots are of this form.

In other words, if there is a rational root in can be written  like $x = \frac{p}{q}$ such that p divides $a_0$ and q divides $a_n$.

If you try all of these combinations of numerators and denominators and none of them is a root, then there are no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$.